# Consider donating to the Internet Archive as part of "Stack Overflow Gives Back"

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, data-dump, donation

As part of "Stack Exchange/Overflow Gives Back", "some of the tools and organizations that make what we do possible" receive donations of USD 1000.

[For 2017](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/12/27/stack-overflow-gives-back-2017/), this is the list:

- LetsEncrypt
- Python Foundation
- HAProxy
- Creative Commons
- Have I been pwned?

(for reference: [2016](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/12/21/stack-overflow-gives-back-2016/) · [2015](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/12/23/stack-overflow-gives-back-2015/) · [2014](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/12/24/stack-exchange-gives-back-2014/) · [2013](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/12/23/stack-exchange-gives-back-2013-2/) · [2012](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/12/21/stack-exchange-gives-back-2012/) · [2011](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/12/23/stack-exchange-gives-back-2011/) · [2010](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/12/25/stack-overflow-gives-back-2010/) · [2009](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/01/stack-overflow-gives-back/))

I’m sure there are many more organizations that would deserve to be part of this list, and I’m not sure if it’s possible to suggest additions, but I’ll try anyway:

**Please consider to donate annually to the Internet Archive ([archive.org](https://archive.org/)).**

**Why?** Not just because the Internet Archive is important, ad-free, non-profit, and [requiring donations](https://archive.org/donate/), but because it hosts the data dumps of all Stack Exchange sites:

[**https://archive.org/details/stackexchange**](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) (currently about 48 GB)

The Internet Archive was part of this list in 2010 and 2011 (i.e., before they were the official location of the data dumps), and part of the mod pick list in 2014.

(I tried to find out if SE is maybe already supporting the IA for providing this service; it’s at least not mentioned in the [announcement from 2014](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/01/23/stack-exchange-cc-data-now-hosted-by-the-internet-archive/), which says "the Internet Archive has agreed to host them" and "we’re really happy to be working with them on this".)